# Swift3 unable to implement the function in another class

Tags: ios, swift3, uigesturerecognizer

I have added gesture in classA for upswipe, If swipe up then the function available in classB has to be called, while calling classB function in classA the function is getting called but the UI changes are not made in classB.

Thanks in advance

```
class A: UIViewController {

      var swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()
      override func viewDidLoad() {
             super.viewDidLoad()

             swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGestureUp))
             swipeUp.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.up
             self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)
      }

      func respondToSwipeGestureUp(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
            if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
                switch swipeGesture.direction {

                case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.up:
                        UserDefaults.standard.set("open", forKey: "status")
                        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
                        print("Swiped up")
                        B().moveUp()
               default:
                        break
               }
          }
     }
}

class B: UIViewController {

    func moveUp()  {

        let status = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "status") as! String
        if status .isEqual("open")
        {
            let fullView1: CGFloat = 100
            self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: fullView1, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check the in `B().moveUp()`, B has been inited yet?

Comment: You are creating new instance of class B... Keep the instance of Class B

Comment: How are you moving from A to B. Protocol and Delegation pattern is relevant here.

Comment: @Mr.Bista Its not navigating from one vc to another if the user swipe in class A then the Ui has to be change in classB

Comment: @VinupriyaArivazhagan i'm not creating new instance i just called the function of classB Will you please tell me whats wrong in it as i new to swift.

Comment: @MaheshNarla, What you want actually, do you want move from Class A to Class B? or else where you instantiate class B

Answer (score 1):

Class B UI does not change because you didn't present `B controller` on navigation. I mean to say If you `controller A` is currently present on screen and on `SwipeGesture` event you are updating the UI using `controller B` whose is not present on screen yet. Why are you doing this and when Did you Push `controller B`.
I hope you got your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make your method as class method

```
class func moveUp() {

// your code

}
```

And call it as:

```
B.moveUp()
```

Comment: he is using self in "moveUp"

Comment: moveUp() method getting called but the UI changes what i want in classB are not made i.e 
 let fullView1: CGFloat = 100
            self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: fullView1, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)